# How to design a view to model automatic conversion on call of web service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, web-services

I have a web application where the user client calls a web service (lets call it **svc1**), which in turn calls another web service (**svc2**) to get some data.

The UI sends an input DTO to **svc1** which converts it to input MODEL for **svc2**, **svc2** then returns output MODEL to **svc1** which is converted to output DTO to be sent to the browser.

The svc1 code is implemented as below:

```
public OutputDto svc1(InputDto dto1){
    InputModel model1 = inputAssembler.convertViewToModel(dto1);
    Output model2 = svc2.call(model1);
    return outputAssembler.convertModelToView(model2);
}
```

I want to know how to implement a design which will take care of calling the `convertViewToModel()` and `convertModelToView()` everytime the **svc1** method is executed. I have the design in such a way that every Model/View pair has an Assembler (Mapper) class that has got two methods called `convertViewToModel()` and `convertModelToView()`

```
interface Assembler<S,T>{ 
    S convertModelToView(T t);
    T convertViewToModel(S s);
}

class InputAssembler<InputDto, InputModel> implements Assembler{
    ....
}
```

I am thinking about AOP, but I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a simple mapper dependency like [MapStruct](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct) , which have functions that automatically map between two Java Beans.This is particularly useful for cases when there is a lot of boiler plate code needed to convert one DTO to model and vice-versa.

The added advantage is that Mapstruct has inbuilt support for spring and Dependency Injection.

The dependency that is needed is  :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.Beta2</version> 
</dependency>
```

Also take care to include the `mapstruct-processor` plugin in pom.

Then you can provide an interface like (not accurate as i don't know your dto class and fields) :

```
@Mapper public interface OutputMapper {
    @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target="id", source="input.id"),
      @Mapping(target="name", source="input.name")
    })
    EmployeeDTO inputToOutputDTO(Input entity);
    @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target="id", source="dto.id"),
      @Mapping(target="name", source="dto.name")
    })
    Employee outputDTOtoInput(OutputDTO dto); }
```

But for your use case i think you will need to use Generic Type Converters. You will have to use java generics to define generic converters for each of the object type.One sample i [found](https://janistoolbox.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/designgeneric-type-converter.html).